# Conditionally rendering a div with React

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

I want to render a div conditionally based on user input in a form.

The user enters a value between 0 - 100 and i have to render the 1 out of 3 divs, based on the value (0 -30, 30-60, 60-100).

Basically i have a form where the user enters the number and below i have to show 1 out of 3 triangles, based on the user input.

Im pretty new to this so would love some help. :D

Comment: Could you please share your form component?

Answer (score 0):

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(null);

  const handleNumberChange = (event) => {
    const value = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);
    setNumber(isNaN(value) ? null : value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={String(number)} onChange={handleNumberChange} />

      {typeof value === 'number' && value >= 0 && value <= 30 && (
        <Triangle1 />
      )}

      {typeof value === 'number' && value > 30 && value <= 60 && (
        <Triangle2 />
      )}

      {typeof value === 'number' && value > 60 && value <= 100 && (
        <Triangle3 />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```